# how to check if a user is a member of sharepoint group or added directly to the site

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Using CSOM powershell how to check if a user is a member of sharepoint group or added directly to the sharepoint site.. Also is there any possibility to check if the user has given permission to the site directly and through Sharepoint group as well.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "added directly to the SharePoint site?"

Comment: permissions given to the site individually not through sharepoint or domain group.